# Не удаётся использовать шифры DHE в nginx, на тесте выходят только шифры ECDHE

Tags: linux, nginx, https, openssl, tls

Настраиваю nginx (v1.16.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1) для использования https. Использую сертификат letsencrypt - SHA-256 с шифрованием RSA. Использую TLSv1.2 Тестирую на ssllabs и observatory . Прописал шифрование следующей строчкой

`ssl_ciphers DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256;`

Тестирую и получаю, что определяется только ECDHE. Пробовал различные комбинации.

[image: ecdhe]

Проблема в том, что мне надо, чтобы шифрование корректно работало с IE11 в версиях Win 7 и Win 8.1, а при тестировании получаю ошибку

> "Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure"

Если на том же ssllabs посмотреть поддерживаемые сертификаты для IE11 Win7, то указана поддержка

> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

которые я и пытаюсь использовать.

[image: win7ie11]

Если указывать кучу лишних поддерживаемых шифрований, то все будет отлично, но все остальные способы шифрования - WEAK.

Конфиг:

```
server {
    listen            443 ssl http2;
    server_name       test.ru;

    ssl_protocols           TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/privkey.pem;
    ssl_ciphers DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

    location / {
            proxy_pass            http://192.168.1.2;
            proxy_redirect        off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            proxy_ssl_name test.ru;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    }
```

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шифры с DH параметрами используются только если указан файл с этими параметрами [в директиве](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_dhparam) `ssl_dhparam`.

Получить параметры можно так:

```
openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048
```

И затем указать явный список шифров:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem
```

Шифры DHE без EC лучше указывать в конце так как их использование подразумевает передачу порядка килобайта при каждой установке соединения.

Проверить выбор шифров можно так:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 test.ru
```

[image: Скриншот где показано что у IE 11 Win7 используется запрошенный набор шифров.]

Всё, готово!

#### Что тут не так?

У такого подхода, с явным заданием шифров, есть недостаток: если в OpenSSL появятся новые шифры, то они не будут использоваться пока вы не обновите список шифров. Кроме того, с этим списком шифров сайт не будет открываться в Safari 8 и более ранних.

Потому, если не гнаться за стойкостью шифров по мнению синтетического теста, и не жертвовать скоростью установки соединения, то проблема совместимости со всевозможными браузерами решается одной строкой:

```
ssl_ciphers "TLSv1.2+ECDHE";
```

Также эта строка решает проблему поддержки более новых шифров.

Как в целом работает [выбор фильтров по тегам можно посмотреть в этой статье](https://habr.com/ru/post/325230/) или [в руководстве к команде](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html).